# FB Graph API return unsuported get request even public post without restriction

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to retrieve post's information from Graph API:

> https://graph.facebook.com/100006679472813_1392957120936924?access_token={my_access_token}

The Facebook Graph response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

However, I can access the post by this link (same user as {my_access_token}) https://www.facebook.com/100006679472813_1392957120936924

And I can receive the original message of this post via Graph Search API too.

Not all posts return error. But so many do. How can I get it's detail via Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

You can not read all the posts in the facebook. If you try to fetch the details of the post by the user other than the user in the session, you may or may not get the details of the post. This depends on the privacy settings of the user. So, only the public posts can be fetched (in case of other users)

Comment: I use the same user token and that post is public!

Comment: You mean that you are fetching the post of the current user (user in session)

Comment: No, that post I fetched from Graph Search API, and current user (in session) can view it, but I can not retrieve it by Graph API. I have tested with other token and get the same result.

Comment: Please clarify, I'm not able to understood what you are trying to say. The answer I've posted is quite clear

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, using an extended page access token I can't get a public post that was put on my page. I'm trying https://graph.facebook.com/post_id?access_token=*, but getting the same code 100 error. Could it be a bug/problem on Facebook's side?

Comment: How could I report a bug to facebook now? I need data in restricted post